# Working in Unreal engine in C++ and want to access FUserOnlineAccount

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I have the following code in unreal engine 4 C++ project

```
FString UCToBluePrintFunctionsLibrary::getUserAccount()
{
IOnlineSubsystem* ion = IOnlineSubsystem::Get();
TSharedPtr<const FUniqueNetId> pid = ion->GetIdentityInterface()->GetUniquePlayerId(0);

IOnlineIdentityPtr OnlineIdentity = ion->GetIdentityInterface();
if (pid.IsValid()) {
    TSharedPtr<const FUserOnlineAccount> userAccount = OnlineIdentity->GetUserAccount(pid);
    return userAccount.GetAccessToken();

}

return FString();
}
```

but it give an error saying:
no suitable user-defined conversion from "TSharedPtr" to "const FUniqueNetId" exists

can any one correct me please?

Comment: I didn't work with unreal engine before but it looks like error is from `OnlineIdentity->GetUserAccount(pid);` can you try to change it to `OnlineIdentity->GetUserAccount(static_cast<FUniqueNetId>(pid));`

Comment: it gives error in FUniqueNetId and says the class is meant to be opaque.

Comment: I put   FUserOnlineAccount userAccount = FUserOnlineAccount::GetAccessToken();
 but it says: Object of abstract class type "FUserOnlineAccount" is not allowed. , any help will be appreciated.